# VMPlayer, Debian 12 Guest, Screen Flicker

Tags: debian, vmware-player

I'm running Debian 12 as a guest in VMPlayer. Depending on what I click, usually a task manager icon, everything on the screen except the desktop image will disappear, even the task manager bar will disappear, then will reappear. But not all (previously) opened apps will reappear. For instance, command (konsole) windows will reappear after the flicker, but browser windows like Firefox, and Brave will not return, their processes even shut down. If Dolphin was running, it will return after the flick. Note, the screen will flicker once, not randomly nor numerous times. It seems to be dependant on what I click.

**Work station specs**

- Gigabyte Z370N WIFI Mini-ITX
- Intel i7 8th Generation
- 32 GB RAM
- NVidia GeForce GTX 1050ti Low Profile
- Window 10 Pro x64 Host (up to date)
- VMWare Player 17.0 (Non Commercial)
- Debian 12 x64 Guest

Any suggestions or fixes are appreciated.

**Edit pertaining to John's comment**

VMWare Tools installed while I was installing Debian. I was prompted and clicked yes or install. My chip has 12 logical processes, I allocated 6 to the Debian guest, also allocated 12 GB RAM to the guest.

Comment: Did you install the VMware Tools inside the guest machine? Did you keep CPU and Memory for the Guest to less than 1/2 the host capability?

Comment: @John, edited my post with respect to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I will look around about the flicker.  None here (Ubuntu and Kali guests).  Do you have the newest host video driver?

Comment: @John, yes I should have stated, everything is up to date, drivers, patches, and updates.

Comment: Two VMware Guest Hardware Settings for Video are 3D Graphics Acceleration and Stretch Mode.  Disable both of these settings and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are struggling with flicker in a VMware Guest machine, two things:

Make certain Host Video Drivers are up to date.

Then go to Settings for the Guest Machine, Hardware Settings,  Video and disable 3D Acceleration.

Also make sure Stretch has not been enabled.

This should help eliminate flicker.

Comment: I have done as such and so far, it hasn't happend, and I've been clicking everywhere to replicate the hard flicker, and it hasn't happened. So I'll declare your response as worked. Thanks.